# Approach to place results of a php script inside a div (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am making a system in which you can place plants on a map. I made a pen that shows what the user will see: https://codepen.io/dcslob/pen/vYxBMdp  The actual map image is missing, but you will get the point.

If you click one one of these pins

```
<div id='25' class='specimen size_20' [...] data-species='Agastache mexicana'>a</div>
```

this div will appear on top of it:

```
<div id='description'>I should be PHP/mysql generated text!</div>
```

I'd like to put some text from the database in this div, based on the id of the plant. However, I am unsure about the way to proceed with this. These are my options:

1. I could preset a separate hidden description div for each species on
   the map when I generate the page. That would add a lot of data if somebody
   uses 100+ species on a map. It would be pretty responsive, though.
2. I could make an ajax request that javascript uses to set the content of the
   description div whenever it is activated.
3. One of you has a far more cunning plan.

This is not a request for a copy/paste solution (I wouldn't mind it, though), I'd like an opinion about the direction I should be looking in, preferably with some examples. I am trying to learn as much as possible from this project, which is why I don't want to use libraries if I can do it myself.

I hope this isn't too wordy, I find it hard to be concise about things I am not sure of myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This really boils down to preferences and your current setup. Do you want to reduce the load on the server or the client? Have you tested either solution? What is the amount of overhead you'd introduce in the first solution? How many requests do you expect would take place in solution #2?

Comment: And, just to satisfy point number 3, you could scan your database to determine the most used species and preload those, use AJAX for the rest. But it's all premature optimization and idle theoreticizing without any real resource assessment.

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful questions for me. I did some testing (getting the info straight from wikipedia went out of the window, for instance), but it's obviously a chicken-egg problem.  I will get down to it!

Comment: The crux of the case is that your dilemma is based on performance, not functionality. Both of the basic solutions you proposed are equally maintainable, because they'd both just read the database. But to make a decision about performance, you would first need to gather some actual usage data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question, based on the input I got from you fine people.

I will ignore the description.php file, that's just reading stuff from the database and printing some simple html.

So clicking one of these divs

```
<div id='78' class='specimen size_20' style='top:334px; left:577px; background-color:rgba(238,130,238,0.5); border-color:rgba(238,130,238,1);' data-sp_nm='Agastache mexicana' data-sp_id='5'>a</div>
```

fires this js function through an event listener (you could probably call it from onClick for testing). The id needed by the db is taken from `data-sp_id='5'`. The map on which the plants are placed has some padding, hence the mouse position corrections.

```
function showDescription( event ){
    
    var species = event.target.getAttribute('data-sp_id');
    var popup   = document.getElementById('description');  
    var map     = document.getElementById('bordermap');  
    var rect    = map.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x       = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y       = event.clientY - rect.top; 
    var descr   = "";
    var xhr     = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url     = "../ajax/description.php";
    var params  = "id="+species;  
     
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);    
    
    xhr.onload = function() {
        // Do whatever with response
        descr               = xhr.responseText;
        popup.innerHTML     = descr;
        popup.style.display = "block";     
        popup.style.left    = x+"px";            
        popup.style.top     = y+"px";  
    } 
}
```

which puts the text in

```
<div id='description' class='description'></div>
```

and makes it popup at the right spot. I added some extra code to make the div draggable and close when you click somewhere outside it. Works like a charm, but I am always up for some improvements or comments.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with option number 2:

> I could make an ajax request that javascript uses to set the content of the description div whenever it is activated.

If the response is a little slow you can always add a loader wheel so the user knows something is going on behind the scenes.

Option number 1 is also a fine approach here but less scalable in general for bigger cases. Also a user will unlikely click on every single case (100+ cases) and in a situation like this I prefer to just retrieve what I need when I need it.

Comment: Thanks, and the last point you offer is indeed something to keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I guess when you're displaying your pins, you're getting them from somewhere, like a DB, or a JSON file.

If it's the case, you can display all pins with a `foreach` instruction.

```
foreach ($pins as $p){
  echo "<div id='25' class='specimen size_20' data-species='Agastache mexicana'>a</div>";
  echo "<div id='description'>Description</div>";
}
```

But to make the pop-up appear/disappear, the ID must be unique. With the solution provided above, a conflict is generated (multiple time the same description id). So let's change the code snippet by this one below:

```
foreach ($pins as $p){
  echo "<div id='id' class='specimen size_20' data-species='Agastache mexicana'>".$p['name']."</div>";
  echo "<div id='description_id' class='description' >".$p['description']."</div>";
}
```

We have to change the JS file to get a proper result.

```
document.addEventListener("click", onClick);

function onClick(){
var className = event.target.className;
var id = event.target.id;
    
 if( className.includes("specimen") ){   
   var popup   = document.getElementById('description_'+id);  
   var map     = document.getElementById('bordermap');  
   var rect    = map.getBoundingClientRect();
   var x       = event.clientX - rect.left;
   var y       = event.clientY - rect.top;
  
    
    popup.style.display = "grid";     
    popup.style.left = x+"px";            
    popup.style.top  = y+"px"; 
 }   
}
```

With this, I'm getting the ID attribute to pass it to the popup, so it can be opened.

I also added the class `description` so in the css file, it can be hidden

Here is a link to try the code: [replit: try the code](https://replit.com/@alexis2m/place-results-of-a-php-script-inside-a-div-without-jQuery#index.php)

**So how can you retrieve data ?**

You can use AJAX and then instead of a PHP array, use a JS one. Or you can use PHP as I did.

Comment: Re-read the question. I don't think you understood what it's really about. By the way, you're still generating duplicate ids.

Comment: I generate the page straight from the db. There are many of these <div id= elements, with many different id's. See the pen. Your approach is the first one on my list above. It's easy to implement, and you only have to make one description for a species, but is it the best approach? That's my question.

Comment: And further reviewing OP's codepen, I don't see any duplicate ids. There's only one element with the id of `description_id` which is merely repositioned (two descriptions cannot be shown at the same time) and all the others were numeric. So you actually introduced duplicated ids where there were none.

Comment: What's your goal ? All approaches are good. To define which one is better, try to define what's exactly needed. With the DB to PHP to Page method I used, you don't get a lot of interactivity. You'll need to add extra JS code to be able to edit pins and move then, etc

Comment: I am sorry, I see where the confusion comes from. The id of the div is not the same as the id of a species. This a quick version of the first approach I was thinking of: https://codepen.io/dcslob/pen/XWMWWrq